# How could I unpivot a dataframe in Spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a dataframe with the following schema:

```
subjectID, feature001, feature002, feature003, ..., feature299
```

Let's say my dataframe looks like:

```
123,0.23,0.54,0.35,...,0.26   
234,0.17,0.49,0.47,...,0.69
```

Now, what I want is:

```
subjectID, featureID, featureValue
```

The above dataframe would look like:

```
123,001,0.23
123,002,0.54
123,003,0.35
......
123,299,0.26
234,001,0.17
234,002,0.49
234,003,0.47
......
234,299,0.69
```

I know how to achieve it if i have only several columns:

```
newDF = df.select($"subjectID", expr("stack(3, 'feature001', 001, 'feature002', 002, 'feature003', 003) as (featureID, featureValue)"))
```

However, I am looking for a way to deal with 300 columns.

Answer (score 0):

You can build an array of `struct` with your columns and then use `explode` to transform them as rows:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{explode, struct, lit, array, col}

// build an array of struct expressions from the feature columns
val columnExprs = df.columns
   .filter(_.startsWith("feature"))
   .map(name => struct(lit(name.replace("feature","")) as "id", col(name) as "value"))

// unpivot the DataFrame
val newDF = df.select($"subjectID", explode(array(columnExprs:_*)) as "feature")
              .select($"subjectID", 
                      $"feature.id" as "featureID", 
                      $"feature.value" as "featureValue")
```